# MySQL procedure with sys_exec()

Tags: php, mysql, function, stored-procedures, laravel-5.1

I'm attempting to fire a Laravel console PHP command to push every inserted row to my client UI, but the procedure doesn't seem to work after installing [lib_mysqludf_sys](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys) libraries for sys_exec()/sys_eval() support.

Environment is the [Laravel Homestead Vagrant VM](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead).  This is running Ubuntu 14.04.3 and MySQL 5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.  I also compiled and successfully installed the lib_mysqludf_sys libraries.

- When using sys_exec(), I get returned exit code 32512 when running the procedure.
- When using sys_eval(), I get no output in my debug_msg output when running the procedure.
- Using the cmd echoed in debug_msg, it runs without issue manually on the CLI.
- No MySQL error.log output

Does anyone know how to further troubleshoot this issue?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS homestead.debug_msg$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS homestead.sessionActivity$$

CREATE PROCEDURE homestead.debug_msg(enabled INTEGER, msg VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  IF enabled THEN BEGIN
    select concat("** ", msg) AS '** DEBUG:';
  END; END IF;
END $$

CREATE PROCEDURE homestead.sessionActivity(id BIGINT)
BEGIN
  IF id THEN BEGIN
   DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
   DECLARE result CHAR(255);
   SET cmd = CONCAT('/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/artisan session:push ', id);
   SET result = sys_eval(cmd);
   #####SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
   call debug_msg(TRUE,cmd);
   #####call debug_msg(TRUE,result);
  END; END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Here is running with debug_msg displaying the cmd variable:

```
mysql> CALL homestead.sessionActivity(74499);
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| ** DEBUG:                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| ** php /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/artisan session:push 74499 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which runs fine manually:

```
root@homestead:~# php /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/artisan session:push 74499
string(259) "new line: some shit eol"
root@homestead:~#
```

Here is running with debug_message displaying the result variable, using sys_exec(), but again, the PHP command is not ran, and no other output or logging shows errors (and sys_eval() instead of sys_exec() output here would be empty):

```
mysql> CALL homestead.sessionActivity(74499);
+-----------+
| ** DEBUG: |
+-----------+
| ** 32512  |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Curiously, while the lib_mysqludf_sys install creates functions, they don't show in show function status.  I'm not sure if it's related.

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION lib_mysqludf_sys_info RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_get RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_set RETURNS int SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS int SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_eval RETURNS string SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.so';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show function status;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lib_mysqludf_sys` calls were being blocked by Apparmor in this case.  A quick `aa-complain /usr/sbin/mysqld` fixes this issue.